# <mvc:argument-resolvers> Not allowed here

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

This is my spring-context file:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<beans:bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:i18n/messages" />
    <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</beans:bean>

<annotation-driven/>
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="WEB-INF/resources/" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.softserve.edu.controller" />

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <ref bean="sortResolver"/>
        <ref bean="pageableResolver" />
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="sortResolver" class="org.springframework.data.web.SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver" />
<bean id="pageableResolver" class="org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver">
    <constructor-arg ref="sortResovler" />
</bean>
...
```

When compiling I get

```
Element 'mvc:annotation-driven' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty
```

Why this error appear and how get this thing to work?
I'm sure that part with  and  is wrong, but I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the schemaLocation to *spring-mvc-3.2.xsd*, it should work. But you have to use `<bean class=""/>` tag to register the resolvers. Bean reference won't work that way

May be try something like this:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <beans:bean id="sortResolver"
            class="org.springframework.data.web.SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver" />
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver">
            <beans:constructor-arg ref="sortResolver" />
        </beans:bean>
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: I changed http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd to http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd, and now it's see <mvc:annotation-driven>
  <mvc:argument-resolvers> but say that <ref is not allowed here.
If you can help me with this I'll be so grateful.

Comment: @Arcaniel Please check my edit. Already did that an hour ago.